# Using Python to keep track of deaths (Twitch bot)

Tags: python

I am working on a command for a twitch bot that will keep track of deaths that the streamer experiences while playing a game. I am trying to have it so someone can do `!addDeath` and a death will be added to the counter. This is how I tried to do it, and obviously it's completely wrong because it doesn't keep track of deaths it just spits out what 0 + 1 is. I need a way for '1' to be added to the `death` value everytime `!addDeath` is executed.

```
def command_addDeath():
    death = 0
    death2 = 1
    sum = float(death) + float(death2)
    print('The sum of {0} and {1} is {2}'.format(death, death2, sum))
    send_message(CHAN, 'Death counter has been updated!')
```

Thank you for your help ahead of time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a variable, called counter. Then, add 1 to the counter every time the function is run:

```
counter = 0
```

Then, make your function, and make sure to bring the variable into scope using the global keyword:

```
def command_adddeath():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    print(counter)
    send_message(CHAN, 'Death counter has been updated!')
```

The reason your function doesn't work is you are setting the variables every time you run it. However, if you have an accumulator, or a counter, you solve this problem.